# Is there any package in R that's commonly used for semi-supervised learning?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, semi-supervised-learning

Is there any package in R that's commonly used for semi-supervised learning ? I have a dataset where I manually labeled 100 data points so I'd like to use semi-supervise learning for the rest of the data sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try for example the upclass package

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/upclass/index.html

There you will find the standard pdf reference and a vignette explaining it all along with examples. I think the function upclassify() would match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Probably irrelevant now, but it might make the answer more complete to also mention the `spa` package as well. It uses a graph-based technique to learn a model. Basically it uses information from both the data point features and how similar data points are to each other. If you have a distance matrix for the data points, it might work well. [This article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i10/v40i10.pdf) explains it with a bit more detail and some examples. You can find the package binary files here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spa/index.html

*edited to provide some additional info about package.*

Comment: Can you say anything about these? Just listing a package &/or a link is considered inadequate here.

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid [link-only answers](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If possible, could you expand it, perhaps by giving a brief discussion about what's in the spa package and perhaps a comparison with the other package mentioned before.

Comment: @gung @Glen_b, done. I don't understand how the initial answer was any different however. Also, `upclass` gathers a variety of different algorithms for data classification, so comparing that to this would be somewhat apples-and-orangesish. Also, with so little info about the inquirer's dataset, there is not much more to be said.

Comment: Your answer came up in the 'low quality' review queue. Most likely, an algorithm picked it for additional scrutiny because it was short and without upvotes. I didn't see the other answer because it wasn't displayed, but you're right about it.